# Python TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying run that little piece of code:

```
mybox = (17.0, -13.0, 489.0644700903291, 566.0)
# this 'box' is my input so these values will vary

xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax = mybox

yValue = range(yMin, yMax, 30)
```

running it, I get an error:

```
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

Is there a way to use a float in a range like that?

Thanks,

Comment: Not completely sure what you're trying to do, but if you really need to use floats there have a look at Numpy's `arange()`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: range is only going to yield integers anyways so just call int() on your parameters before passing them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for arange, which can be found in numpy (or pylab).

```
import numpy
...
yValue = numpy.arange(yMin, yMax, 30.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case numpy is too heavy of a dependency, there is also a `numeric_range` function in the `more_itertools` library, that works will all the data types:

```
from more_itertools import numeric_range
from fractions import Fraction

start = Fraction(1, 2)  # Start at 1/2
stop = Fraction(5, 2)  # End at 5/2
step = Fraction(1, 2)  # Count by 1/2

list(numeric_range(start, stop, step))
# gives [Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(3, 2), Fraction(2, 1)]
```