# TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float?

Tags: python, floating-point

I know this has been asked before, but the answers did not help me :/

I created a function that runs a for loop over the squared max of the inputs, and by all accounts my code is correct...and yet it still asks for float inputs.

```
def spiral(X, Y):

x = y = 0
dx = 0
dy = 0
count = 0

for i in range(max(X, Y)**2):
    if (-X/2.0 < x <= X/20) and (-Y/2.0 < y <= Y/2.0):
        print (x, y)

    if x == y or (x < 0 and x == -y) or (x > 0 and x == 1-y):
        dx, dy = -dy, dx

    x, y = x+dx, y+dy
```

print spiral(3.0,3.0)

And I get this error: `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.`

But I put 3.0 when I try and print the function...so what am I missing?

Thanks :)

Comment: You're passing in floats for the values of `X` and `Y`, pass in integers instead.

Comment: this is how I call the function: print spiral(3.0, 3.0)

Comment: @Chef1075 -- Exactly.  `3.0` has type `float`, not `int`.  :-).

Comment: `for i in range(max(int(X), int(Y))**2):`

Comment: That worked. So I read it as...expecting float got integer. Exactly opposite.

Comment: Floating point parameters apart, maybe your code is correct, or maybe you should set one of dx or dy to 1...

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090050/python-typeerror-range-integer-end-argument-expected-got-float

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like others said in the comment, the problem is mainly because of the float value in range function. Because range function won't accept float type as an argument.

```
for i in range(max(int(X), int(Y))**2):
```